# How do you sort 'should have [obligation]' and 'should have [expectation]'?

Tags: modal-verbs

> He should have been there.

means that "I think he had a duty to go there, but failed", doesn't it?

> He should have been there by yesterday.

and this implies "I think he might have arrived there at least not later than yesterday".

Then, how do you make a sentence which means "I think he had a duty to go there not later than yesterday, but failed" using with should've? This would seem kinda stupid question, but I'm struggling... please teach me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can mean either one or both depending on the context of the conversation.

If I was complaining to someone that the plumber hadn't come to fix a leak yet I would say, "He should have been here an hour ago," meaning he should have been there by obligation **and** by a certain time.